Error while trying to run moxios test - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')
I have a class where I am making an axios instance in the constructor. This class also has service methods (omitted in the snippet):-


export class CartCreationService extends SuperClass {
  public static axiosInstance: AxiosInstance;
  constructor(serviceName: string) {
    super(serviceName);
    CartCreationService.axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: Configuration.NEW_CART_API,
      headers: {
        [Constants.CONTENT_TYPE]: Constants.APPLICATION_JSON,
        [Constants.X_API_KEY]: Configuration.CLIENT_SIDE_API_KEY,
        [Constants.CORRELATIONID]: Configuration.CORRELATIONID,
        [Constants.ADD_EFFECTIVE_PRICE]: true
      }
    });
    CartCreationService.axiosInstance = Utils.setAxiosLogInterceptor(CartCreationService.axiosInstance);
  }
}



In my Mocha test file, this is what I have. I'm importing the same axios instance from my class and using it to call a service method:-


describe("Test", () => {
  let cartCreationService;

  before(() => {
    cartCreationService = CartCreationService.Instance();
  });
  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install(CartCreationService.Instance().axiosInstance);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall(CartCreationService.Instance().axiosInstance);
  });
  let requestJSON = {
    "data": {}
  };
  const cartId = "036336e2ca5519f840dc";
  const mainItemId = "";
  it.only("should return", async() => {
    let requrl = "url";
    moxios.stubRequest(requrl, {
      status: 200,
      responseText: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cart))
    });
    try {
      const result = await cartCreationService.addAccessoryToCart(requestJSON, cartId, mainItemId);
      expect(result.type).to.equal("Cart");
      requrl = "";
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error ->", error);
    }
  });
});



I'm always getting an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url') in the catch block. Where am I going wrong?

I found the issue. I was calling my class instance from my test file, not the direct axios instance. It's working now that I used this:-


beforeEach(() => {
  moxios.install(CartCreationService.axiosInstance);
});
afterEach(() => {
  moxios.uninstall(CartCreationService.axiosInstance);
});



